# zsh programmatically populate command content

Tags: bash, zsh

I'm writing myself a script to optimize workflow. I want to populate the command programmatically, e.g. if I run myscript, I want it to prepopulate a string "this is great" in the next prompt:

```
% myscript
% this is great
```

Is this possible?
I'm using zsh, but it'll be better if this can be achieved using common bash commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `print` command takes a `-z` option that does what you want:

```
% print -z hi
% hi
```

Note, though, this only works within a single shell instance. If you include this in a script, you'll have to *source* the script:

```
% . myscript
% hi
```

not execute it in a separate process

```
% zsh myscript
%
```

I'm unaware of any equivalent functionality in `bash`.